# Find text in span withoud ID and replace jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, replace

How can I find and change text which is in span and in div which don't have IDs?

```
<div style="text-align:center;float:left;width:100%;fontsize:12px;padding:12px 0 16px 0;line-height:1.25em;">
                            **VOLUME (24H)**                        
<br><br>                        
<span style="font-size: 14px; ">**$2.99 M**</span>                    
</div>
```

I want to find `VOLUME (24H)` and `$2.99 M` which is not constant and replace with my text. How can I do that?

I can't put IDs, because I get this from this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://files.coinmarketcap.com/static/widget/currency.js"></script>
<div class="coinmarketcap-currency-widget" data-currency="nexus" data-base="PLN" data-secondary="" data-ticker="true" data-rank="false" data-marketcap="false" data-volume="true" data-stats="USD" data-statsticker="false">    
</div>
```

Comment: Html context could help... do you have some static element (with id, class, attribute, whatever) close?

Comment: Because I get that code from `https://files.coinmarketcap.com/static/widget/currency.js`

Comment: In that case, if the values are not constant, and the markup is added to children of the `coinmarketcap-currency-widget` class element, then your only recourse is to find the elements positionally within their positional parent(s).

Comment: Is that content the direct child of the `coinmarketcap-currency-widget` class div?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/UEUrXmhq here's html code

Answer (score 1):

Going completely positional, which is very very fragile.

```js
var $div = $('.coinmarketcap-currency-widget').find('> div > div:nth-child(2) > div');
var $contents = $div.contents();

console.log($contents.eq(0).text().trim());
console.log($contents.eq(5).text().trim());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="coinmarketcap-currency-widget" data-currency="nexus" data-base="PLN" data-secondary="" data-ticker="true" data-rank="false" data-marketcap="false" data-volume="true" data-stats="USD" data-statsticker="false">
  <div style="border:2px solid #E4E6EB;border-radius: 10px;font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;min-width:285px;">
    <div>
      <div style="float:right;width:67%;border: 0px solid #000;text-align:left;padding:5px 0px;line-height:30px;">
        <span style="font-size: 18px;"><a href="http://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/nexus/?utm_medium=widget&amp;utm_campaign=cmcwidget&amp;utm_source=&amp;utm_content=nexus" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(66, 139, 202);">Nexus (NXS)</a></span>
        <br>
        <span style="font-size: 16px;">13.55 PLN <span style="color:#d14836">(-5.34%)</span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div style="text-align:center;padding:5px 0px;width:33%;"><img src="https://files.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/nexus.png"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="border-top: 1px solid #E4E6EB;clear:both;">
      <div style="text-align:center;float:left;width:100%;font-size:12px;padding:12px 0 16px 0;line-height:1.25em;">
        VOLUME (24H)
        <br>
        <br>
        <span style="font-size: 14px; ">$3 M</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="border-top: 1px solid #E4E6EB;text-align:center;clear:both;font-size:10px;font-style:italic;padding:5px 0;">
      <a href="http://coinmarketcap.com?utm_medium=widget&amp;utm_campaign=cmcwidget&amp;utm_source=&amp;utm_content=nexus" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(66, 139, 202);">Powered by CoinMarketCap</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: seems that this code doesn't work, i always get empty console log
https://pastebin.com/N5WfTa3n